# WSL Postgres Connections

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm struggling to get Rails up and running through Windows Bash - for some reason, PostgreSQL is requiring passwords for all TCP/IP connections. It does not prompt for a password when connecting through a unix socket. Ideally my environment would never require a password.

All the advice I can find on this issue points to modifying the `pg_hba.conf` file. I've edited mine accordingly - there's only one (v9.5). I've reloaded the config via `select pg_reload_conf();` and restarted the service to no avail.

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I've tried to remove the password from the default "postgres" account, but it still requires the password "root" when I try to connect via `$ psql -h localhost -U postgres`. When I supply no password, I get `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied` and the prompt terminates.

I've created a new role, `root`, with no password. This has the same behavior, except the password "root" doesn't work - I'm not sure what password it expects, but it does expect one.

Little lost on what to do next. Everything I can find online points to modifying the `pg_hba.conf` file to look similar to what I have. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling postgresql packages, but ran into the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are editing the wrong `pg_hba.conf`? You can check that with `show hba_file`

Comment: Nope, editing the right one - I got the original location using that command